# Insert ckeditor html code into the database

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

I am trying to insert the ckeditor text into database,I am able to print the code in html format,while inserting that into the db,iam getting the fallowing error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table' at line 1
```

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/smaple.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<textarea rows="20" cols="70" class="ckeditor" id="editor1" name="test1"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**action.php**

```
<?php
echo strip_tags($_POST['test1']);
$content  = $_POST['test1'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$conn = mysql_select_db("test");
$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES('','one',mysql_real_escape_string($content)";
echo $query;
if(mysql_query($query))
{
    echo "inserted";
}
else
{
    mysql_error();
}
$display = "select * from table";
$res = mysql_query($display);
if($res)
echo "true";
else
echo mysql_error();
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo $res['content'];
}
?>
```

please help me

Comment: you are missing one `closing round bracket in your query`... it should be `$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES('','one',mysql_real_escape_string($content))";`

Comment: actual error is table name,we should not give the table as table name

Comment: ohhk.. but you can put your table name in ` symbol.. i dont know what the name of this symbol... on the esc key...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the line to read:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO myTableName VALUES('','one','".mysql_real_escape_string($content)."'";
```

And make sure you're putting the right value for your table name in place of **myTableName**...

Comment: blue it is perfectly working,we should not define table name with the table write?

Comment: @Manju - I believe one could use `table` as a table name, but I'd advise on choosing a better name, avoiding the [**Reserved Words**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/reserved-words.html) list.

Comment: Warning This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

Answer (score 1):

Closing braces for the query is missing.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES('','one',mysql_real_escape_string($content))";
```

Answer (score 1):

It's work for me

index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="action.php" method="post">
<textarea rows="20" cols="70" class="ckeditor" id="editor1" name="test1">       </textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

action.php

```
<?php
echo strip_tags($_POST['test1']);
$content  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['test1']);
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$conn = mysql_select_db("test");
$query = "INSERT INTO yourtablename VALUES('','$content')";
echo $query;
if(mysql_query($query))
{
    echo "inserted";
 }
 else
{
mysql_error();
}
 $display = "select * from yourtablename";
 $res = mysql_query($display);
 if($res)
 echo "true";
 else
 echo mysql_error();
   while ($result = mysql_fetch_row($res)) {
   echo $result[1];
  }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your table name which is like any keywords from sql then take it in this symbol `  on the top of tab button

Answer (score 0):

You can do i without using mysql_real_escape_string($content)

You  can directly use 
$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES('','one','$content')";